# Omniauth and strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, strong-parameters

So this is probably going to be a very dumb question but i've set up Oauth with twitter as the provider in a similar way to Ryan Bates's 'Simple Omniauth Railscast - my question is now that that is set up and working should i be setting strong parameters in my sessions controller or is this not necessary?

**SessionsController.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def create

    @user = User.find_by_uid(auth_hash[:uid]) || User.create_user(auth_hash)

    session[:uid] = @user.id

    if @user

      redirect_to root_path

    else

      redirect_to root_path, flash: {signinerror:  "Oops, something went wrong with your sign in. Please try again."}

    end
  end

  def auth_hash

    request.env['omniauth.auth']

  end

  def destroy

    session[:uid] = nil

    redirect_to root_path

  end
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :opinions

  def self.create_user(auth_hash)
        create do |user|
            user.provider = auth_hash[:provider]
            user.name = auth_hash[:info][:name]
            user.uid = auth_hash[:uid]
            user.username = auth_hash[:info][:nickname]
            user.email = auth_hash[:info][:email]
            user.image = auth_hash[:info][:image]
        end 
  end   

end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't use mass assignment on object creation, strong parameters will not give you any additional security.

> With this plugin Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted.

https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters